# What is the permission for a IAM user to create a ECR repository?

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

My IAM user is getting this error

```
User: arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/admin is not authorized to perform: 
ecr:CreateRepository on resource: *
```

when I try to create a repository.

[image]

I have already grant `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceFullAccess` to the group this user belongs to. I search for repository in 'attach policy' but there is no match. How can I grant the permission  to this user?

Answer (score 6):

The required permission is `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess`

Comment: What is the trick to find this?

Answer (score 5):

I got this error some time back, notice that you have given "containerservicefullaccess" and not "ContainerRegistryFullAccess"

Answer (score 1):

ECR has its own IAM policies, so you need to give your user additional permissions for it
[Here you can find documentation about ECR policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr_managed_policies.html)